# Components not having the expected props, while React and Redux Dev Tools are having the expected States and Props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning react-redux, so I decided to implement what I have been learning. But I am have a bug challenge. So I console.logged `this.props.users` from `mapStateToProps` function.

I believe there's something I not doing right which I don't understand. Please an explanation in other to move on. Thanks you so much for helping out.

Here is my code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUsers } from '../actions/userAction';
import UserList from '../components/UserList';

class UserPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.users);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Users Page</h2>
        <UserList users={this.props.users} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    users: state.userReducer.users
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers())
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserPage);
```

So this is what I get from the chrome console - Empty arrays.
[props showing empty arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ed8Q.png)

But when I check the React DevTool and Redux DevTool, they display the expected Props and States respectively. Below are the snapshot of the dev tools

[React devtool shows the correct Props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Cb0.png)

[Redux devtool show the correct States and Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amSto.png)

userAction.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import * as types from './actionTypes';

export let fetchingUser = () => {
  return {
    type: types.FETCHING_USERS
  };
};

export let fetchedUser = payload => {
  return {
    type: types.FETCHED_USER,
    payload
  };
};

export let fetchUser_error = () => {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_USER_ERROR
  };
};

export let fetchUsers = () => {
  let url = 'https://eventcity.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users';
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchingUser());
    return axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => {
        const users = response.data.data;
        dispatch(fetchedUser(users));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(fetchUser_error());
      });
  };
};
```

userReducer.js

```js
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCHING_USERS:
      return { ...state, users: [], error: null, loading: true };
    case types.FETCHED_USER:
      return { ...state, users: action.payload, error: null, loading: false };
    case types.FETCH_USER_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [],
        error: { message: 'Error loading data from the API' },
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

configureStore.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from '../reducer/rootReducer';

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
};

export default configureStore;
```

rootReducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userReducer from './userReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  userReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to check this
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/129. Your problem is using componentDidMount and componentWillMount without having a better understanding of what they are used for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with redux, all you need to understand is that your `fetchUsers` request is `async` and `componentDidMount` function is only executed once after the component has rendered and it may so happen that the data is not present by the time `componentDidMount` function is executed and hence your `console.log(this.props.users);` return empty array, Log it in the render method and you will see the correct data

```
class UserPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.users);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Users Page</h2>
        <UserList users={this.props.users} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your swift response